# How do I find a customer's files using SuiteTalk?

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am attempting to create a .NET program that calls the NetSuite web services to return a list of files associated to a customer.

I have set the ShopperJoin to the customer I've searched for, but the web call still returns all files in the File Cabinet.

```
FileSearch file = new FileSearch();
CustomerSearchBasic custBasic = new CustomerSearchBasic();
custBasic.entityId= new SearchStringField();
custBasic.entityId.@operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.contains ;
custBasic.entityId.operatorSpecified = true;
file.shopperJoin = custBasic;
file.basic = new FileSearchBasic();custBasic.entityId.searchValue = "ID";
SearchResult result = _service.search(file);
```

I am using the 2015 SuiteTalk wsdl
https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2015_1_0/netsuite.wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting NetSuite support, I learned that I had taken the wrong approach.

Files can be filtered based on customer via a customer search.

I was able to create a CustomerSearchAdvanced request that retrieves associated files.

When you create that, you add the columns you want to the FileJoin object in the request, and it will find the files based on whatever customer criteria you set up.

```
CustomerSearchAdvanced attachSearch = new CustomerSearchAdvanced();

SearchColumnStringField[] stringcols = new SearchColumnStringField[1];
stringcols[0] = new SearchColumnStringField();

SearchColumnStringField[] stringcols = new SearchColumnStringField[1];
stringcols[0] = new SearchColumnStringField();

attachSearch.columns = new CustomerSearchRow();
attachSearch.columns.fileJoin = new FileSearchRowBasic();
attachSearch.columns.fileJoin.internalId = selcols;
attachSearch.columns.fileJoin.description = stringcols;
attachSearch.columns.fileJoin.name = stringcols;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the customer id and the folder id are the same? (just a hunch)